# How to display an XML file in browser or text file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an .xml file that I would like to simply make more human readable, it does not have to be of superior formating, just simply readable. I would like to accomplish this either in the browser or a text file.

I did find a snippet of code that was 'supposed' to display it in a more readable format but I am unable to get it to do so. I get a browser that displays nothing.

Here is the code that I put in the file:

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="the file name" ?>`

I am currently using IE8 I cannot update browser as it is a company workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a website link that can solve your problem. It is follwing: http://xmlgrid.net

It has grid and a text view and is very simple to use. Good luck.

Comment: That is a great website. Thank you. I do not want to use it because the xml file I am using has sensitive information on it and I don't want it crossing over the Internet by my hands, the file itself will be handed off to the customer and they need to be able to view it in a somewhat decent format. So I would like to write some code in it.

I will still bookmark that site though!